# Why is linux not listing the IP I want?

Tags: linux, ip, address

I have a linux based cluster (using openMosix). The machine intended to be used as a server has 2 network cards. Cluster is working, and all machines ping to each other inside the cluster (internal network).

However, I set the server's public IP as static, to be XXX.XXX.198.247. If I do a ifconfig in the console, it shows me that the machine is indeed xxx.xxx.198.247. Pinging "myself" does work. However, If I use an external site to check my IP (i.e. ping.eu) it shows me as xxx.xxx.198.231. Trying to ping  both xxx.xxx.198.247 and xxx.xxx.198.231 from the syte or from other machines conected to the internet results in no response (total package loss).

Here's my etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.105
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address xxx.xxx.198.247/24
netmask 255.255.255.224
network xxx.xxx.198.0
broadcast xxx.xxx.198.255
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.195.14
dns-search laborator[/code]
```

I'd apreciate any help.

Comment: This is a routing problem.

Answer (score 1):

What's at `198.231`?  Presumably it's a NAT address for traffic being sent to the internet via your `192.168.1` network?

Your default gateway's on the inside interface, so that's the path that will be taken to get the internet.  You'll need to determine what you want this server's networking configuration to look like from a routing perspective; perhaps default gateway on eth1 and a static route for `192.168.0.0/16` on eth0?